# Why is ( ) used instead of curly braces / brackets { } inside Javascript Map function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

Inside map function why is the function defined with ( ) => **( )** instead of ( ) => **{ }**

```
  {mylist.map((elem, index) => (
            <div key={elem.id}>
              <h2>{elem.title}</h2>
            </div>
          ))}
```

Comment: Because it's not using a block body, just wrapping a single expression.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Ok I accept your answer if the code would be in 1 line . As I know we can omit curly braces / brackets if the return statement is only 1 line . BUT we have multiple lines of code so { } should be used .

Comment: You can omit them if the return is only one _expression_, it can span multiple _lines_.

Comment: Lines do have syntax significance in JavaScript, it's not Python.

Answer (score 11):

You can leave () out if you put everything in one line:

```
 {mylist.map((elem, index) => <div key={elem.id}><h2>{elem.title}</h2></div>)}
```

If you want to return something, but it take several lines, then you have to use ():

```
{mylist.map((elem, index) => (
    <div key={elem.id}>
        <h2>{elem.title}</h2>
    </div>
))}
```

Finally, when you want to perform something and THEN return the result, you need to use {}. You still need to care when you return something - if it takes several lines, you have to wrap it with():

```
{mylist.map((elem, index) => {
    const id = elem.id;
    const title = elem.title;
    return (
        <div key={id}>
            <h2>{title}</h2>
        </div>
    );
})}
```

For returning objects it's also a bit different: You can wrap your object into brackets: `({...})` or explicitly return it: `() => { return { ... }}`

Comment: Also, if you want to return an object you use `()`: `list.map(item => ({ ... }))`